# algorithm with no ends but left thread

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I like the `noend` option from `algorithmicx` because it makes the layout
of the algorithm closer to the python syntax my students use.

But to make it even clearer, i'd like to have left threads on the left to visually empashise the indented block.

Like this:
[image]

Comment: Similar: [Vertical loop/block lines in algorithmicx with 'noend' option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144840/79060)

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ : Sorry I didn't see the lots of work already done...