# Get a list of icon definitions with icons having the line height and vertically aligned to the lines

Tags: graphics, lists

I'm currently trying to define a list of icons/images which will take the size of the line height and be vertically aligned to the lines. This list is basically a list to explain what are these icons about. The example below is what I want to achieve, and is taken [from the Apple iOS documentation website](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/DesigningaUserInterface.html).[image]

I grabbed the images from there, but these are a bit larger than the actual line height. Specifying and including the images as it without resizing them should thus produce a rendered version with each image a bit greater than expected. What is weird is that this isn't what I got as rendered version: some images appear way greater than others. I know each image differs lightly in size from the others (e.g.: 26x30, 30x30, 36x32, etc.) but AFAIK this couldn't be reason and explain that issue.

[image]

I thought that reducing the size of each image (and keep their ratio) using the size of the line would be enough, like [described here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics#Including_graphics). Unfortunately, since [this is not possible to determine the height of the line we are currently in](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100922/determine-height-of-the-line-you-are-in) as it depends on a bunch of factors: space between lines and font size, etc.

I then decided I should just scale each image using a value that could suit the rendered version using trial and error, but this value isn't automatically computed and as soon I change the size of the text, I need to recompute the value manually. Not really efficient. I got a some better result, but I've still the problem some images appear really smaller than others.

[image]

To solve the centering problem I thought to the command `\vcenter` but I've some issues with it: it requires me to be in math mode and the rest of the line appears outside the page borders.

[image]

The ugly code I've for now:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item $\vcenter{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{fig_xcode_inspector_file}} Some text$
    \item $\vcenter{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{fig_xcode_inspector_quick_help}} yet some text$
    \item $\vcenter{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{fig_xcode_inspector_identity}} some text$
    \item $\vcenter{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{fig_xcode_inspector_attributes}} some text$
    \item $\vcenter{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{fig_xcode_inspector_size}} some text $
    \item $\vcenter{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{fig_xcode_inspector_connections}} some text $
\end{itemize}
```

Any help helping me to solve this issue is welcome.

Comment: Why `scale`? do you know they have the same size to begin with? Again I think the `adjustbox` package can help a lot.

Comment: @daleif I need to scale them because they are a bit too large to fit the line height. And like I said, they aren't all exactly the same size, so why are you writing "they have the same size to begin with"?
And I followed your advices, I'm using the 'adjustbox` package for other purpose than this question.

Comment: @daleif I looked the package `adjustbox` more in details, and even if I have the values `maxheight`, I still need to compute the height value manually :-/

Comment: Why, what is wrong with just `height=1em`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \includegraphics[valign=b,height=\fontcharht\font`X]{example-image} Some text
    \item \includegraphics[valign=b,height=\fontcharht\font`X]{example-image-a} Some text
    \item \includegraphics[valign=b,height=\fontcharht\font`X]{logo} Some text
    \item \includegraphics[valign=b,height=\fontcharht\font`X]{pecemblem} Some text    
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `\fontcharht` e-TeX?  It seems like it isn't available in Knuth TeX.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, it is eTeX. but you can get around it in this case, if need be.

Comment: Yes, as I'm using LaTeX with the xelatex TeX engine, this isn't compiling. If you have a pure LaTeX/TeX variant, that would be cool ;-)

Comment: @wget This will compile with xelatex for me. I am using miktex 2.9 duly updated.

Comment: @HarishKumar Indeed, the problem was on my side. And it [indeed](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2006-June/004144.html) comes from eTeX, but the XeTeX engine understands this command. This is quite weird as XeTeX is said to be built on TeX + LaTeX, not on eTeX.
IIUC, the eTeX command `\fontcharht` calculates the height of the font letter defined with `\font`, but I don't understand well what `\`X` is about and what it does exactly.

Comment: @wget It is the height of `X` Change `X` to `x` and you will see the change.

Answer (score 4):

If you'd wanted center alignment (as your `\vcenter` suggested) then I'd recommend `adjustbox` as Harish showed, but here I think you are better with the default baseline alignment. I'd just do

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \includegraphics[height=.7em]{example-image} Some text
    \item \includegraphics[height=.7em]{example-image-a} Some text
    \item \includegraphics[height=.7em]{logo} Some text
    \item \includegraphics[height=.7em]{example-image-b} Some text    
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But as wanted to have the icons a bit taller, I defined 1em instead of 0.7. By using this value, we clearly see the alignment isn't correct. I surrounded \includegraphics by adjustbox like advised and defined the `valign` key to `m`, which should correctly align the icon vertically, but in practise this isn't. I tried to redefine the value of `\adjboxvcenter` like described in the doc, but didn't got any positive result.
I don't know how to redefine that macro :-/ I'm always getting its value printed on the page and not taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `\vcenter` is what you are looking for.  A good estimate for the line height is given by `\fontdimen22\textfont2+1ex` which is the height of the math axis plus the height of the letter `x`.  The `$\null\mathsurround=0pt$` is there to initialise the math fonts in TeX, else you will get an error message that there are only 7 fontdimens in nullfont.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\icon[2]{%
  $\null\mathsurround=0pt$%
  \includegraphics[height=\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2+1ex\relax]{#1}
  \textbf{#2.}\space
}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \icon{example-image-a}{File} Some text
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Here I set the icon in place of the bullet, though that can be changed by removing it from the `[ ]` brackets.  Also, here, I set the icons to the vertical extent of a cap `X`, though I comment out an alternative approach where the height may be explicitly specified, with the icon sitting on the baseline of the specified height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,scalerel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\def\seticon#1{%
  \scalerel*{\includegraphics{#1}}{X}% SCALES TO SIZE OF CAP X
%  \scaleto{\includegraphics{#1}}{2ex}% SPECIFY THE HEIGHT OF THE SCALE
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item [\seticon{example-image}] Some text
    \item [\seticon{example-image-a}] Some text
    \item [\seticon{ARL_Logo_March2012_BlackGold}] Some text
    \item [\seticon{sbs2}] Some text    
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the alternate form, setting the icons to 2ex height on the baseline.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you can find and use a suitable icon font (here I've used [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), which requires XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX), you can drop the images entirely and the scaling with font size problem is handled automatically. Other benefits are higher-quality symbols, infinite scalability, and smaller PDF file size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newcommand{\myitem}[2]{\item #1 {\bfseries\sffamily #2}}

\def\testlist{%
\begin{itemize}
  \myitem{\faFile}{File.} Specify general information about the storyboard.
  \myitem{\faQuestionSign}{Quick Help.} Get useful documentation about an object.
  \myitem{\faThumbnailsList}{Identity.} Specify a custom class for your object 
    and define its accessibility attributes.
\end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}\sffamily
{\testlist\par}

{\huge\testlist\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but unfortunately, I must use the icons provided on the Apple website or use my own, I have been unable to find font that could suit the one provided by Xcode.