# How to display line height in the text

Tags: line-spacing

I know there are all sorts of commands to change the line height.

But I would like to display it, just like I do with font size `\fontname\font\` or `\@font`.
My question is different then [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100922/determine-height-of-the-line-you-are-in) as I don't mind how the baseline is calculated of if it changes during the text.

I'm interested in the default value for the given font size.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}
This text is \fontname\font\ or \@font with %\baselineskip
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\baselineskip` is height + depth, you can display it using `\the\baselineskip` or [`printlen`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/printlen). The height would be something like `\ht\strutbox` and can be printed also with `\the\ht\strutbox` or [`printlen`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/printlen)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `\the` to print a length in `pt` or package [`printlen`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/printlen) to print it in any unit.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{printlen}

\begin{document}
This text is \fontname\font\ with font size \csname f@size\endcsname{}
and \verb|\baselineskip| =~\the\baselineskip =~\uselengthunit{mm}\printlength{\baselineskip}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more information about the current font see [`fntguide`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/fntguide.pdf), section 2.3.

Comment: That works like a charm. Thank you. I think what i'm looking for is the Leading, which seems to be `\the\baselineskip`